# Conditional show list column based on current MUI language in SP2010?

Tags: multilingual, xslt

I have a list in a SharePoint 2010 site which has two columns for a description - one in English and the other in French. I'd like to be able to show only the column that matches the language currently selected in the MUI. I've been digging around in SPD with conditional formatting and so far can't find anything that seems to fit the bill. Is this even possible via XSLT or do I need to get into custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get into code... In fact, you could use an already buit solution, there are 2 around that could be useful to you.  I would advice you to go with IceFire, a MUI and multiple language content manager that is working quite well.  I'va implemented it in 3-4 scenarios and it always did the trick.  The only problem, it not free...

Check it out here : http://www.icefire.ca/